# scrapy logging in issue with InitSpider

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to do an authenticated scrapy login with `InitSpider`. For some reason, with `InitSpider` it ALWAYS fails to login. My code is similar to the answer in the below post:

[Crawling LinkedIn while authenticated with Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953991/crawling-linkedin-while-authenticated-with-scrapy)

The response I see in logs is this:

```
2012-12-20 22:56:53-0500 [linked] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://example.com/> from <POST https://example.com/>
```

Using the code from the above post, I have the same `init_request`, `login`, and `check_login_response` functions. I can see with log statements that it reaches the `login` function, but it seems to never reach the `check_login_response` function.

When I re-implement the code using `BaseSpider`, and I do the `FormRequest` in the `parse` function, i'm able to login with no issue. Is there a reason for this? Is there something else I should be doing? Why am I getting a redirect for logging in with `InitSpider`?

**[EDIT]**

```
class DemoSpider(InitSpider):
    name = 'linked'
    login_page = # Login URL
    start_urls = # All other urls

    def init_request(self):
        #"""This function is called before crawling starts."""
        return Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)

    def login(self, response):
        #"""Generate a login request."""
        return FormRequest.from_response(response, 
            formdata={'username': 'username', 'password': 'password'},
            callback=self.check_login_response)

    def check_login_response(self, response):
        #"""Check the response returned by a login request to see if we are successfully logged in."""
        if "Sign Out" in response.body:
            self.log("\n\n\nSuccessfully logged in. Let's start crawling!\n\n\n")
            # Now the crawling can begin..
            return self.initialized()
        else:
            self.log("\n\n\nFailed, Bad times :(\n\n\n")
            # Something went wrong, we couldn't log in, so nothing happens.

    def parse(self, response):
        self.log('got to the parse function')
```

Above is my spider code.

Comment: paste the full code of your spider class

Comment: Just added the code for it.

Comment: When I have this kind of issues I debug the HTTP requests and responses with wireshark. Which version of scrapy are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After struggling with this for a bit, I figured it out, and I posted the solution on my blog:

http://tmblr.co/ZjkSZteCOTyH

Basically I use `BaseSpider` and I override the `start_requests` method to handle the login.