# Download error on http://pypi.python.org/simple/PACKAGE: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname - Python Library HTTPLib Issue?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, httplib

I'm trying to download some packages (currently, the google API) via pip - but I'm getting this response:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo easy_install google-api-python-client
Searching for google-api-python-client
Best match: google-api-python-client 1.3.1
Processing google_api_python_client-1.3.1-py2.7.egg
google-api-python-client 1.3.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_api_python_client-1.3.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for google-api-python-client
Searching for uritemplate>=0.6
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/uritemplate/
Download error on http://pypi.python.org/simple/uritemplate/: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname -- Some packages may not be found!
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/uritemplate/
Download error on http://pypi.python.org/simple/uritemplate/: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'uritemplate' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on http://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for uritemplate>=0.6
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('uritemplate>=0.6')
```

Now, I figured I'd ask here instead of on RPi.SE since this seems to have been asked and answered here several times already. Now, normally, that would constitute *not* asking again - but none of these solutions have helped.

I've looked at

- [python pip installation error 'cannot fetch base index URL'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27000121/python-pip-installation-error-cannot-fetch-base-index-url)
- [DNS lookup failed: address 'your.proxy.com' not found: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917292/dns-lookup-failed-address-your-proxy-com-not-found-errno-5-no-address-ass)
- [pip can not install anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416938/pip-can-not-install-anything)
- [Error while installing with Python “pip”: Cannot fetch index base URL http//:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724779/error-while-installing-with-python-pip-cannot-fetch-index-base-url-http)

just to name a few.

Several of these solutions mention a proxy issue causing this error - however, that isn't my problem, as I don't have a proxy and my $http_proxy is null:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ echo $http_proxy

pi@raspberrypi ~ $
```

Another issue that was mentioned was the lack of the proper SSL version and the solution given was to install pip 1.2.1...now that seems a bit outdated. Do I need to install a certain version of OpenSSL/pip?

I *did* install pip 1.2.1, I had 1.1.1 previously (the package from the Raspbian repositories) but got the same error.

Any idea what might be causing this?

**EDIT: Is it an HTTPLib error?**

I believe that this is an issue with the Python installation on my Raspberry Pi, because I'm getting the same error (`[Errno -5] No address associated with hostname`) in some other code of mine using the `httplib` python library. An issue in the httplib library would definitely explain this issue.

Note, `curl`, `wget`, and `lynx` all work just fine.

Comment: But you can access `https://pypi.python.org/simple/uritemplate/` from your browser, using `wget` or things like that?

Comment: @cel Correct. I can access it both via `wget` and via Firefox on my desktop.

Comment: Sorry, `wget` in a shell on your `rpi` right?

Comment: @cel Correct, `wget` works on my Pi.

Comment: @cel I think it's actually an issue with httplib, as I'm having the exact same error with some more of my own code that uses httplib - Error 5

Comment: You are probably right. Maybe someone else can jump in. :)

Comment: @cel That's just it... no one has - and I need HTTPLib for a project that's due in 4 days! EEK!

Comment: Did you have a look at this thread: http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=75435

Comment: @cel I was just reading through that when you commented - I tried the temporary solution and it worked! Yay!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue with a work-around, as per [this post on the Raspberry Pi Forums](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=75435&p=561999).

I had to edit the `create_connection()` function in the `/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py` file to resolve the hostname to an IP first:

**Original Code:**

```
def create_connection(.....)

host, port = address
err = None
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
```

**Edited Code:**

```
def create_connection(.....)

host, port = address
err = None
hostip = gethostbyname(host)
for res in getaddrinfo(hostip, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
```

Comment: +1 , thanks ! It solved my problem ! I think this should go into standard /usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py to fix this bug