# Xpath Error - Spider error processing

Tags: xpath, scrapy

So i am building this spider and it crawls fine, because i can log into the shell and go through the HTML page and test my Xpath queries.

Not sure what i am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. I have re installed Twisted, but nothing.

My spider looks like this -

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from spider_scrap.items import spiderItem

class spider(BaseSpider):
name="spider1"
#allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
start_urls = [                  
              "http://www.example.com"
            ]

def parse(self, response):
 items = [] 
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//*[@id="search_results"]/div[1]/div')

    for site in sites:
        item = spiderItem()
        item['title'] = site.select('div[2]/h2/a/text()').extract                            item['author'] = site.select('div[2]/span/a/text()').extract    
        item['price'] = site.select('div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/b/text()').extract()     
    items.append(item)
    return items
```

When i run spider -  scrapy crawl Spider1   i get the following error -

```
    2012-09-25 17:56:12-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines:
    2012-09-25 17:56:12-0400 [Spider1] INFO: Spider opened
    2012-09-25 17:56:12-0400 [Spider1] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped  0 items (at 0 items/min)
    2012-09-25 17:56:12-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
    2012-09-25 17:56:12-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
   2012-09-25 17:56:15-0400 [Spider1] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.example.com>  (refere
   r: None)
   2012-09-25 17:56:15-0400 [Spider1] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET    http://www.example.com
    s>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1178, in mainLoop
        self.runUntilCurrent()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 800, in runUntilCurrent
        call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 368, in callback
        self._startRunCallbacks(result)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 464, in _startRunCallbacks
        self._runCallbacks()
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 551, in _runCallbacks
        current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spider.py", line 62, in parse
        raise NotImplementedError
    exceptions.NotImplementedError:

     2012-09-25 17:56:15-0400 [Spider1] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
     2012-09-25 17:56:15-0400 [Spider1] INFO: Dumping spider stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 231,
     'downloader/request_count': 1,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 186965,
     'downloader/response_count': 1,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 25, 21, 56, 15, 326000),
     'scheduler/memory_enqueued': 1,
     'spider_exceptions/NotImplementedError': 1,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 25, 21, 56, 12, 157000)}
      2012-09-25 17:56:15-0400 [Spider1] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
      2012-09-25 17:56:15-0400 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping global stats:
    {}
```

Comment: Which line in spider.py is line 62?

Comment: Line 62 - def parse(self, response):
        raise NotImplementedError

Comment: The indentation isn't right in the code fragment you posted. You might want to double check that in you script.

Comment: Like Leo said, fix the indentation problems and post the code you're actually running, then get back to us.

Comment: I was just indenting(spacing up), so that it gives the CODE block thing. Hence the spaces.

Answer (score 12):

For everyone who faces this problem, please, make sure you didn't rename parse() method like I did:

```
class CakeSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name            = "cakes"
    allowed_domains = ["cakes.com"]
    start_urls      = ["http://www.cakes.com/catalog"]

    def parse(self, response): #this should be 'parse' and nothing else

        #yourcode#
```

Otherwise it throws the same error:

```
...
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spider.py", line 62, in parse
    raise NotImplementedError
    exceptions.NotImplementedError:
```

I've spent like three hours trying to figure out -.-

Answer (score 3):

Leo is right, the indenting is not correct.  You probably have some tabs and spaces mixed up together in your script because you pasted some code and typed in other code yourself and your editor allowed for both tabs and spaces in the same file.  Convert all tabs to spaces so it's more like:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from spider_scrap.items import spiderItem

class spider(BaseSpider):
    name = "spider1"
    start_urls = ["http://www.example.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        items = []
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//*[@id="search_results"]/div[1]/div')

        for site in sites:
            item = spiderItem()
            item['title'] = site.select('div[2]/h2/a/text()').extract
            item['author'] = site.select('div[2]/span/a/text()').extract
            item['price'] = site.select('div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/b/text()').extract()
            items.append(item)

        return items
```

Answer (score 2):

your parse method is out of class code , use bellow mentioned code

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from spider_scrap.items import spiderItem

class spider(BaseSpider):
    name="spider1"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = [
      "http://www.example.com"
     ]

    def parse(self, response):
        items = []
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//*[@id="search_results"]/div[1]/div')

        for site in sites:
            item = spiderItem()
            item['title'] = site.select('div[2]/h2/a/text()').extract                            item['author'] = site.select('div[2]/span/a/text()').extract
            item['price'] = site.select('div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/b/text()').extract()
        items.append(item)
        return items
```