# How can i follow the links if i don't subclass from crawl spider in scrapy

Tags: python, django, scrapy

This is my code and my spider is not following links
I have sub class from InitSpider

```
class TestSpider(InitSpider):
    name = 'login'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']
    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('example\.com', 'PostSearch'),restrict_xpaths = "//dd[@class='nextPage']"), callback='parse_items', follow=True),)

    def parse_items(self, response):

        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
```

- am using this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/5857202/1894766*

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: i don't get any error but it don't follow any links except the start url given

Comment: Which website are you crawling and how are you running the crawl? `scrapy crawl someurl`?

Comment: it can be any website , can u just give me simple example where where u subclass from `initSpider` and it follows link. if i subclass from crawlspider then its working fine. i am crawling amazon by scrapy crawl myspidername