# Scrapy issue when logging in and scraping all links

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to get Scrapy to login to a website, and then being able to goto particular pages of it and then scrape information. I have the below code:

```
class DemoSpider(InitSpider):
    name = "demo"
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    login_page = "https://www.example.com/"
    start_urls = ["https://www.example.com/secure/example"]

    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'\w+'),callback='parse_item', follow=True),)

    # Initialization
    def init_request(self):
        """This function is called before crawling starts."""
        return Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)

    # Perform login with the username and password
    def login(self, response):
        """Generate a login request."""
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={'name': 'user', 'password': 'password'},
                    callback=self.check_login_response)

    # Check the response after logging in, make sure it went well
    def check_login_response(self, response):
        """Check the response returned by a login request to see if we are
        successfully logged in.
        """
        if "authentication failed" in response.body:
            self.log("Login failed", level=log.ERROR)
            return

        else:
            self.log('will initialize')
            self.initialized(response)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.log('got to the parse item page')
```

Everytime I run the spider, it logs in and gets to the initialize. However, it NEVER matches a rule. Is there a reason for this? I checked the below site regarding this:

[Crawling with an authenticated session in Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851213/crawling-with-an-authenticated-session-in-scrapy)

There're also a number of other sites including the documentation. Why is it that after initializing, it never goes through the `start_urls` and then scrapes each page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use rules in `InitSpider` . Its only available in `crawlspider`

Comment: Yes, I realized this later.

Comment: Darn!  I thought init spider inherited from crawlspider.  :(

Answer (score 1):

From looking at other questions, it would appear that you need to return self.initialized with no parameters ie `return self.initialized()`