# Scrapy crawling stackoverflow questions matching multiple tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I am trying out scrapy now. I tried the example code in http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/intro/overview.html page. I tried extracting the recent questions with tag 'bigdata'. Everything worked well. But when I tried to extract questions with both tags 'bigdata' and 'python', the results were not correct, with questions having only 'bigdata' tag coming in the result. But on browser I am getting questions with both the tags correctly. Please find the code below:

```
import scrapy

class StackOverflowSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'stackoverflow'
    start_urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bigdata?page=1&sort=newest&pagesize=50']

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.css('.question-summary h3 a::attr(href)'):
            full_url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(full_url, callback=self.parse_question)

    def parse_question(self, response):
        yield {
            'title': response.css('h1 a::text').extract()[0],
            'votes': response.css('.question .vote-count-post::text').extract()[0],
            'body': response.css('.question .post-text').extract()[0],
            'tags': response.css('.question .post-tag::text').extract(),
            'link': response.url,
        }
```

When I change start_urls as

> start_urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bigdata+python?page=1&sort=newest&pagesize=50']

the results contain questions with only 'bigdata' tag. How to get questions with both the tags only?

**Edit**: I think what is happening is that scrapy is going into pages with tag 'bigdata' from the main page I gave because the tags are links to the main page for that tag. How can I edit this code to make scrapy not go into the tag pages and only questions in that page? I tried using rules like below but results were still not right.

```
rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css='.question-summary h3 a::attr(href)'), callback='parse_question'),)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The url you have (as well as the initial css rules) is correct; or more simply:

```
start_urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+bigdata']
```

Extrapolating from [this](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/), this will also work:

```
start_urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bigdata%20python']
```

The issue you are running into however, is that stackoverflow appears to require you to be **logged in** to access the multiple tag search feature.  To see this, simply log out of your stackoverflow session and try the same url in your browser. It will redirect you to a page of results for the first of the two tags only.

TL;DR the only way to get the multiple tags feature appears to be logging in (enforced via session cookies)

Thus, when using `scrapy`, the fix is to authenticate the session (login) before doing anything else, and then proceed to parse as normal and it all works. To do this, you can use an [`InitSpider`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851213/crawling-with-an-authenticated-session-in-scrapy/5857202#5857202) instead of `Spider` and add the appropriate login methods.  Assuming you login with StackOverflow directly (as opposed to through Google or the like), I was able to get it working as expected like this:

```
import scrapy
import getpass
from scrapy.spiders.init import InitSpider

class StackOverflowSpider(InitSpider):
    name = 'stackoverflow'
    login_page = 'https://stackoverflow.com/users/login'
    start_urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bigdata+python']

    def parse(self, response):
        ...

    def parse_question(self, response):
        ...

    def init_request(self):
        return scrapy.Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)

    def login(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={'email': 'yourEmailHere@foobar.com',
                              'password': getpass.getpass()},
                    callback=self.check_login_response)

    def check_login_response(self, response):
        if "/users/logout" in response.body:
            self.log("Successfully logged in")
            return self.initialized()
        else:
            self.log("Failed login")
```