# How to keep a session authenticated while crawling with scrapy?

Tags: python, session, scrapy, web-crawler

I have followed the response for this question ([Crawling with an authenticated session in Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851213/crawling-with-an-authenticated-session-in-scrapy)) to use scrapy with an authenticated session. The problem is that it seems to log in successfully, but when I make a request it seems to be unauthenticated.
Any idea on where the problem is?

Here is my python script:

```
enter code here
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders.init import InitSpider
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

class LoginSpider(InitSpider):
    name = demo
    login_page = #login page
    inquery = #search query
    start_urls = #urls with queries

    def init_request(self):
        return scrapy.Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)

    def login(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
        return [scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formid='login-form',
                    formdata={'username': 'username', 'password': 'password'},
                    callback=self.after_login)]

    def after_login(self, response):
        # check login succeed before going on
        open_in_browser(response)

        if "invalid username or password" in response.body:
            self.log("Login failed", level=log.ERROR)
            print "FAILED"
            return
        else:
            self.log('authentication succeed')
        return scrapy.Request(url=self.inquery, callback=self.parsse)

    def parsse(self, response):
        for result in response.xpath('//div[@class="span9"]/div[@class="search-result"]/div/a[@class="details"]/@href'):
            print 'new resutl'
            url = response.urljoin(result.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_details_contents)

    def parse_details_contents(self, response):
        item = ShodanItem()
        for details in response.xpath('//ul[@class="services"]/li'):
            item['ip'] = response.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/h2/text()').extract()
            item['services_arr'][0] = details.xpath('/div[1]/div[1]/text()').extract()
            item['services_arr'][1] = details.xpath('/div[1]/div[2]/text()').extract()
            item['services_arr'][2] = details.xpath('/div[1]/div[3]/text()').extract()
            item['services_arr'][3] = details.xpath('/div[2]/h3/text()').extract()
            item['services_arr'][4] = details.xpath('/div[2]/pre/text()').extract()

            print item['services_arr'][4]
            yield item
```

Here is the log, I assume it does log in as it redirects to the main page, but afterwards, using the `open_in_browser()` command I get a page that asks for authentication in order to use the query:

```
dsds
    2016-07-06 15:07:51 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-07-06 15:07:51 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-07-06 15:07:51 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-07-06 15:07:52 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://account.shodan.io/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2016-07-06 15:07:52 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://account.shodan.io/login> (referer: None)
2016-07-06 15:07:52 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.shodan.io/?language=en> from <POST https://account.shodan.io/login>
2016-07-06 15:07:53 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.shodan.io/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2016-07-06 15:07:53 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.shodan.io/?language=en> (referer: https://account.shodan.io/login)
2016-07-06 15:07:53 [shodan.io] DEBUG: authentication succeed
2016-07-06 15:07:54 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.shodan.io/search?query=org%3A%22Instituto+Tecnol%C3%B3gico+y+de+Estudios+Superiores+de%22> (referer: https://www.shodan.io/?language=en)
ASDASDASDASDASDASDASDASDASD
2016-07-06 15:07:54 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-07-06 15:07:54 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 2231,
 'downloader/request_count': 6,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 5,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 11759,
 'downloader/response_count': 6,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 4,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 6, 20, 7, 54, 214825),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 8,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'request_depth_max': 2,
 'response_received_count': 5,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 4,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 4,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 4,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 4,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 6, 20, 7, 51, 797093)}
```

Comment: What happens exactly? Does it print `FAILED`?

Comment: No, it seems to log in as it redirects to the main page, but after that, when I enter the url with the query it responds with an error page asking for authentication. I will attach the log in the description.

Answer (score -1):

I found by enabling the cookies debugger `COOKIES_DEBUG = True` in the configuration file that the authentication was being done correctly. By messing with the configuration file, I managed to make the script work and crawl the site authenticated.
For anyone with the same problem, I added`ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False` and changed the user agent to the one of a web browser: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36`