# Using Scrapy for Crawling Pages Post Authentication

Tags: authentication, scrapy

Taking cues and ideas from a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850755/using-scrapy-with-authenticated-logged-in-user-session/5850928#5850928) , I tried to come up with my own code.

However, using my code I've noticed that it doesn't really scrape anything and probably doesn't go beyond the authentication level at all. I say this because I don't see any Error Logs even when I put an incorrect password.

My best guess is that the HTML for the authentication fields is not contained in a "Form" tag and hence the formdata is possibly overlooking it. Might be wrong.

My Code so far:

```
class LoginSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'auth1'
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/administration']

    def parse(self, response):
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={'employee[email]': 'xyz@abc.com', 'employee[password]': 'XYZ'},
                    formxpath='//div[@class="form-row"]',
                    callback=self.after_login)]

    def after_login(self, response):
      if "authentication failed" in response.body:
        self.log("Login failed", level=log.ERROR)
        return
    # We've successfully authenticated, let's have some fun!
      else:
        return Request(url="http://www.liveyoursport.com/administration/customers",
               callback=self.parse_tastypage)


    def parse_tastypage(self, response):
      sel = Selector(response)
      item = Item()
      item ["Test"] = sel.xpath("//h1/text()").extract()
      yield item
```

Here's the HTML section:

```
<div class="content-row">
  <div class="special-header-title span_full">
    <h3><span class="blue-text">Sign </span>In</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content-row">
  <div class="form-section checkout-address-edit span_80" id="sign-in-form" >
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/employees/sign_in" class="new_employee" id="new_employee" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="HQYZa0hNZ2Y+UvtbIk9OxI48Hlsnt+MiYOeV9ql2yWo=" /></div>
      <div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-col-1"><label for="employee_email">Email</label></div>
          <div class="form-col-2">
            <input id="employee_email" name="employee[email]" size="30" type="email" value="" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-col-1"><label for="employee_password">Password</label></div>
          <div class="form-col-2">
            <input id="employee_password" name="employee[password]" size="30" type="password" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row form-row-controls">
        <div class="form-col-1"></div>
        <div class="form-col-2">
          <input class="sign-in-button f-right" name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign in" />
        </div>
      </div>
</form>    <br>


  <a href="/employees/password/new">Forgot your password?</a><br />


  <a href="/employees/unlock/new">Didn&#x27;t receive unlock instructions?</a><br />


  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.FormRequest.from_response):

> **formxpath (string)** – if given, the first form that matches the xpath
>   will be used.

but it seems that you are not matching the `form`, rather the parent `div`.
Try it like this:

```
return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={'employee[email]': 'xyz@abc.com', 'employee[password]': 'XYZ'},
                    formxpath='//form[@id="new_employee"]',
                    callback=self.after_login)]
```

Also, if you only have one `form` element on the page, you don't need to define `formxpath`.