# Using Scrapy Shell with FormRequest

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

Trying to log into a CMS membership site with code from [scrapy document](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html) and fellow [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850755/using-scrapy-with-authenticated-logged-in-user-session?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I keep coming up short. My error messages:

```
2017-03-20 18:18:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://members.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2017-03-20 18:18:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://members.com/wp-login.php> (referer: None)
2017-03-20 18:18:07 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <POST http://members.com/login.php> from <POST http://members.com/login.ph
p?wpe-login=membersipa>
```

I tried changing user agent to:

```
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0'
```

But my errors were:

```
2017-03-20 17:47:20 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET     http://members.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2017-03-20 17:47:22 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://members.com/wp-login.php> (referer: None)
2017-03-20 17:47:23 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (403) <POST http://members.com/wp-login.php?wpe-login=membersipa> (referer: http://members.com/wp-login.php)
2017-03-20 17:47:23 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <403 http://members.com/wp-login.php?wpe-login=membersipa>: HTTP status code is not handled or not
allowed
```

This is the code that produced the errors:

```
import scrapy

class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'freddy'
    start_urls = ['http://members.com/wlogin.php']

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'log': 'name', 'pwd': 'password'},
            callback=self.after_login
        )

    def after_login(self, response):
        # check login succeed before going on
        if "authentication failed" in response.body:
            self.logger.error("Login failed")
            return
    else:
            return Request(url="http://members.com",
               callback=self.parse_ipro)

    def parse_ipro(self, response):
        title = response.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/main/article/header/h1').extract_first()
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

Ultimately, I would like to use scrapy shell to test selectors and tried using scrapy

Tried with scrapy shell but also knocked on butt:

```
import scrapy

class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'freddy'
    start_urls = ['http://members.com/wlogin.php']

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'log': 'name', 'pwd': 'password'},
            callback=self.after_login
        )

    def after_login(self, response):
        # check login succeed before going on
        if "authentication failed" in response.body:
            self.logger.error("Login failed")
            return
```

And tested this in shell:

```
response.xpath('//title/text()').extract_first()
```

but received 301 and 302 redirections

after adding:

```
def parse(self, response):
    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        headers={'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'User-Agent':
                 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'},
        formdata={'log': 'Name', 'pwd': 'Password', },
        callback=self.after_login
    )
```

the message changed to:

```
2017-03-22 03:46:07 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-03-22 03:46:07 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-03-22 03:46:07 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 
2017-03-22 03:46:08 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://members.com/login.php> (referer: None)
2017-03-22 03:46:08 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://members.com/login.php> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely missing some headers in your `FormRequest`.

Open up networks tab in your browser tools, find the requests you are looking for and look under "request headers" part (see related issue [Can scrapy be used to scrape dynamic content from websites that are using AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550114/can-scrapy-be-used-to-scrape-dynamic-content-from-websites-that-are-using-ajax)). Some of the headers are not necessary and some are already included by `FormRequest`, however some are not so you need to replicate those.

Usually it's `Content-Type` header that needs to be replicated.

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'json/...',
}
req = FormRequest(url, formdata=form, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @granitosaurus. I added content for steps taken based on your suggestions. Also, the header in posts (using firebug) is as follows:                                                                                            log: name
pwd: password                                                                               redirect_to: http://members.com/admin/
testcookie: 1
wp-submit: Log In