# Response.css() is giving no results for pagination in scrapy crawler after login

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-shell

I want to read 'title' of list of projects which are in pagination & 335 records almost.
What i am trying to do is :
1) First I get response of the browser by this command in windows cmd:

```
scrapy shell https://www.slingshotinsights.com/projects
```

2)It shows the HTML rendered in cmd, and very next i write

```
reponse.css('a.grey-link').extract()
```

and press enter, it gives me [] 'empty array'.

**The question is, How to get data from scrapy script for the URL's which appears after login?** Because https://www.slingshotinsights.com/projects is the link, which comes when user successfully login the page.

And may be scrapy is unable to find that

```
reponse.css('a.grey-link').extract()
```

css selector becuase it can't be loaded in logout view.

Comment: You have to login to that website if website is displaying data for logged in user only ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Scrapy with authenticated (logged in) user session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850755/using-scrapy-with-authenticated-logged-in-user-session)