# Scrapy rows output is in the wrong order

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

### How can I manipulate the ORDER of the ROWS - or simply output them in the same order as they appear on the website?

(I cannot output the results according to the order on the website in the .csv file.)

---

I have managed to arrange the **columns** with FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS (via settings.py):

`FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS = ["brandname", "devicecount",  "phonename"]`

However, every attempt to sort the **rows** has been unsuccessful.

---

This is the code:

```
import scrapy
from gsm.items import GsmItem
    
class GsmSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'gsm'
    allowed_domains = ['gsmarena.com']
    start_urls = ['https://gsmarena.com/makers.php3']
    
    # LEVEL 1 | all brands

    def parse(self, response):
        
        item = GsmItem()

        gsms = response.xpath('//div[@class="st-text"]/table//td')
        for gsm in gsms:
            allbranddevicesurl = gsm.xpath('.//a/@href').get()
            brandname = gsm.xpath('.//a/text()').get()
            devicecount = gsm.xpath('.//span/text()').get()
            
            item['brandname'] = brandname
            item['devicecount'] = devicecount

            yield response.follow(allbranddevicesurl, callback=self.parse_allbranddevicesurl,
                                    meta= {'brandname': item,
                                           'devicecount': item
                                    })

    # LEVEL 2 | all devices

    def parse_allbranddevicesurl(self, response):
        
        item = response.meta['brandname']       
        item = response.meta['devicecount'] 

        phones = response.xpath('//*[@id="review-body"]//li')
        for phone in phones:
            detailpageurl = phone.xpath('.//a/@href').get()

            yield response.follow(detailpageurl,
                                    callback=self.parse_detailpage,
                                    meta= {'brandname': item,
                                           'devicecount': item
                                    })

        next_page = response.xpath('//a[@class="pages-next"]/@href').get()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse_allbranddevicesurl,
                                    meta= {'brandname': item,
                                           'devicecount': item
                                    })

    # LEVEL 3 | detailpage

    def parse_detailpage(self, response):
     
        item = response.meta['brandname']       
        item = response.meta['devicecount']
         
        details = response.xpath('//div[@class="article-info"]')
        for detail in details:
            phonename = detail.xpath('.//h1/text()').get()
                
            yield item
```

---

**I would be grateful for a suggestion on how to solve this problem.**

---

Comment: What is your `response` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to introduce the following custom settings in settings.py:

```
DEPTH_PRIORITY = 1
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1
SCHEDULER_DISK_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeues.PickleFifoDiskQueue'
SCHEDULER_MEMORY_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeues.FifoMemoryQueue'
```

The solution is also mentioned here:
[scrapy-spider-output-in-chronological-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47337917/scrapy-spider-output-in-chronological-order)
and here
[does-scrapy-crawl-in-breadth-first-or-depth-first-order](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-scrapy-crawl-in-breadth-first-or-depth-first-order)